# after editing when update button press ,no data change why

Tags: php, sql

i want to make admin panel.my problem is that after editing show data but when edit the data and update no any data changes in database no changes
plz help me and give me correct direction

MY FIRST PHP FILE

```
 <?php
    $conn=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','admin');
    $sql="SELECT * FROM admin";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    while($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $id=$row['id'];
        $name=$row['name'];
        $email=$row['email'];   
    ?>
    <table>
            <form action="111.php" method="post">
            <tr><td><?php echo $id ?></td><td><?php echo $name ?></td><td><?php echo $email ?></td><td></td><input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id ?>">
            <td><input type="submit" name="edit" value="edit"></td></tr></form>
    </table>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

MY SECOND PHP FILE

```
  <?php
    $conn=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','admin');
    if(isset($_POST['edit']))
    {
        $id=$_POST['id'];
        $sql="SELECT * FROM admin where id='$id'";
        $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
        {
        $id=$row['id'];
        $name=$row['name'];
        $email=$row['email'];
    ?>
    <form action="2017.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id ?>">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name ?>">
    <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="update" value="update">
    </form>

    <?php
    }
    }
    ?>
```

MY THIRD PHP FILE

```
<?php
$conn=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','admin');
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
    $id=$_POST['id'];
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $sql="UPDATE admin SET name='$name' AND email='$email' where id='$id'";
    mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    echo "successfully update";
}
?>
```

Comment: admin is a table name or database name ?

Comment: no error but data not updated

Comment: admin database and admin table

Comment: yes echo successfully update but in database no data changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to separate fields in `UPDATE` query with `commas` not with `AND.`

Correct:

```
$sql="UPDATE admin SET name='$name' AND email='$email' where id='$id'";
```

To:

```
$sql="UPDATE admin SET name='$name', email='$email' where id='$id'";
```